# Pass view model with parameters to POST method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to build my application with DI (pure 3-tier application)

One ViewModel class fills some its fields in contructor:

```
public class RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel
{
    public RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel(PixlocateBusinessLogic.IStaticListRepository repository)
    {
        Country = new ListViewModel<Pair<string, int>>();
        State = new ListViewModel<Pair<string, int>>();

        PixlocateBusinessLogic.StaticListService service = new PixlocateBusinessLogic.StaticListService(repository);
        var countries = service.CountryList();
        var states = service.StateList();

        foreach (var item in countries)
        {
            Country.List.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem() { Text = item.CountryName, Value = item.CountryID.ToString() });
        }

        foreach (var item in states)
        {
            State.List.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem() { Text = item.StateName, Value = item.StateID.ToString() });
        }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Country is required")]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public ListViewModel<Pair<string, int>> Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public ListViewModel<Pair<string, int>> State { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographer()
    {
        ViewModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel model = new ViewModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel(_staticListRepository);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographer(ViewModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             // some actions
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Of course, I get an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

when I post form to the server. 
Of course, I can't remove parameter from RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel constructor.
How can I say "pass parameter" to POST method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is , when you post the form data, the DefaultModelBinder will try to create an object of your view model and try to map the posted form data to the properties of your view model object. Since your view model does not have a parameter less constructor, it is failing while trying to create an object of your view model.

You need to create a default parameterless constructor in your view model.

```
public class RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel
{
    public RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel(){}
    public RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel(IStaticListRepository repository)
    {
      // Existing code   
    }
 // Existing code   
}
```

Also IMHO, it is not a good idea to mix your data access code inside your view model class. View models are supposed to be lean-flat POCO classes speicifically for transferring data between your views and action method. If you try to mix your data access code inside that, you are making tight coupling and breaking the Single responsibility principle.

You should change data/webservice call from your view model and move it to another layer ( Your action method/ BL etc).

Simple sample.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
  IStaticListRepository repository;
  public CustomerController(IStaticListRepository repository)
  {
    this.repository= repository;
  }
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
    var vm = new RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerViewModel();
    // using the repository object, populate the vm properties
    return View(vm);
  }
}
```

Comment: "Also it is not a good idea to mix your data access code inside your view model class." - where I miss it? I call it from special class, passed as abstraction (interface). In your example you have to fill model twice (in GET and PUT methods), also, I want to use Validation of model, how to call it without passed repository?

Comment: "View models are supposed to be lean-flat POCO classes" - for example, it would be better to have view model, which validate itself (i.e. implement IValidatable). It's no POCO class at all